Weekly question limit: is there other than 1?
In moderator tools we have an option to see a number of questions that particular user able to ask on weekly basis. I could found only "1" and "0" (in case of no restrictions):






* text on screenshots is autotranslated back from Russian to English
Is there other possible weekly limits for questions posting? I didn't find such information in The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide
At the same time we have some strings in localization engine that refer to the number of questions on weekly basic as variable, e.g.:

limited to $numQuestions$ question(s) per week

Thus, developers expected that this number may vary.

Why are you asking a mod tools question on public meta?

@Nij because it's OK for some questions that don't reveal any sensitive information

@W.O. yes, I think it's like leaked implementation details: zero used as "no limit".

There is no logical inconsistency in the second picture. Nor is there any reason why this question needs to be asked or answered.

@CodyGray A upper limit of zero questions per week sounds like a prohibition on creating questions.

But it's not. If your weekly question limit is zero, then you are not limited to how many questions you are able to ask per week.

"Limit is value" can also mean "number ≤ the value", so no, it's ambiguous. I wouldn't lose any sleep over it though.

It might be ambiguous, but it's not a logical inconsistency or contradiction. In fact, if one interpretation creates an inconsistency/contradiction, then this can reasonably be taken as resolving the ambiguity, right, @Andras?

It's probably stored as a bit column in SQL Server.

@Glorfindel very likely it is. But to be sure, I think only someone from the staff can confirm.

This question is similar to: The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

There are (perhaps confusingly) two different views of this same information in the moderator tools:

Note the blue box, where it says "limited to 1 question per week: no" and the "Restrictions" section (as you quoted), where it says "Weekly question limit: 0". These are the same thing. Other information is duplicated here, too, such as "blocked from asking: no"/"Question ban: no" and "blocked from answering: no"/"Answer ban: no".
It seems that the confusion arises from the fact that what is clearly represented as a Boolean state in the blue box ("limited to 1 question per week", with either a "yes" or "no" answer) is ambiguously represented in the "Restrictions" section ("Weekly question limit") as a numeric value. That condition can either be a 0 or 1, which is equivalent to a Boolean "yes"/"no", but only if you know that in advance. If you don't, you might erroneously assume that it could be any integer. It can't; if you are limited to 1 question per week, then that's your limit. If you're not limited (0), then you have no limit.

So your assumption is based only on the data from light blue area right? But at the same time we have some strings in translation engine that have variable for number of questions. For example here.
